DinkToPDF issues on Mac M1 - conversion process hangs
I'm trying to integrate DinkToPDF to convert my HTML reports to PDF in my application. I've made console PoC based on developer's sample and it works fine - I can see that the wkhtmltopdf process starts, reports progress and finishes with code 0.
When I applied the same code to my application being a class library with couple of services and run a test of this particular service the conversion process starts, reports 10% of progress and stops responding - has to be killed. Obviously no logs available, no exceptions.
Any clues what can be wrong? Both console application and class library uses the same .net framework. The only difference is that in case of class library I'm using xunit test with fixture to access the service - maybe that's the reason.
        var converter = new BasicConverter(new PdfTools());
        
        converter.PhaseChanged += Converter_PhaseChanged;
        converter.ProgressChanged += Converter_ProgressChanged;
        converter.Finished += Converter_Finished;
        converter.Warning += Converter_Warning;
        converter.Error += Converter_Error;
        
        var doc = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
        {
            GlobalSettings = {
                ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
                Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
                PaperSize = PaperKind.A4
            },
            Objects = {
                new ObjectSettings() {
                    PagesCount = true,
                    //HtmlContent = content,
                    HtmlContent = @"<html><body><h1>Test</h1></body></html>",
                    WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8" },
                    FooterSettings = { FontSize = 9, Right = "Page [page] of [toPage]" },
                    LoadSettings = { BlockLocalFileAccess = false }
                }
            }
        };
        byte[] pdf = converter.Convert(doc);

and the test part:
 var srv = fixture.Provider.GetService<IReportGenerator>();
            
 var req = new ReportReq 
            { 
                TemplateName = "test_report",
                Lang = "en-US",
                Data = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "Text", "Some test text..." }
                },
            };
            var res = srv.Generate(req, test_template_dir);

